# Is it possible to enable the tab key as an indentation instead of "cycle" on android?

Tags: samsung, android-11

I planned to use my phone+external keyboard combo as my primary means of taking notes (replacing my laptop since it is more portable).

Everything works great except for `tab` key for indentation. Android input it as `cycling through options`, similar to `alt` key on desktop.

I heavily use tab indentation in my note-taking since the note-taking-style is a heavily nested markdown file, so the `tab` key is a very important and frequently used key. For example:

```
# title
- subtitle 1
  - point 1
    - subpoint 1
    - subpoint 2
  - point 2
    - subpoint 1
      - subsubpoint 1
  - ...
- metadata:
 - date: 2021-3-3, tuesday
 - location: Kyoto, uni cafe
- ... etc. (you got the idea)
```

Is it possible to make `tab` key to `insert indent` / disable shortcut?

Thank you in advance for your kind help!

Edit per Morrison Chang suggestion:

The apps I used were [Samsung Notes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.app.notes&hl=en&gl=US) and [Markor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.gsantner.markor&hl=en&gl=US). I will try with different apps to see if these are isolated behaviors within these apps.

Comment: You should [update your post](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/239469/edit) with the name of apps where you are encountering this issue. [Using tab key to change field focus is suggested practices in the Android Developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/navigation#Tab) so word processing/note taking apps will probably have alternative modes/settings.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I will try some more apps and check the settings if there's a toggle to change the behavior.